# Accessing a specific method of an inherited class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I come from Java background and I have the following little scenario that doesn't fit my understanding:

```
template<typename T>
class GeomObject{
  public:
    T position;

    virtual Vec3<T> getPosition() = 0;
}


template<typename T>
class Plane : public GeomObject<T> {
  public:
    Vec3<T> position;
    T range;

    Vec3<T> getPosition() { return position; }
    T getRange() { return range;}
}
```

In my main:

```
vector<GeomObject<float>*> g_objects;
g_objects.push_back(new Plane<float>());

g_objects[0]->getRange(); //ERROR
```

I cannot access the getRange() method somehow. This was possible in Java but here is not, not even by casting *(Sphere)g_objects[0]->getRange();* I would like tho, to keep the vector as a vector of *GeomObjects* . Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: GeomObject does not have getRange member.

Comment: @NathanOliver that getRange is not a method of my object. I thought that by creating a specific instance of _Plane_ I would have been able to access its methods, while I can access only those of his parent--> geomObject

Comment: Just a note here you'd get the same error in Java. Your using polymorphisim to use an interface to call methods on an object. You're calling a method not in the interface you're using.

Comment: Search for and read about *downcasting*. But be warned that you must make sure that the object you use is actually of the correct type. Also, IMHO excessive downcasting is a sign of a flawed design.

Comment: You could have done that using a cast, `static_cast<Plane<float>*>(g_objects[0])->getRange()`, but that doesn't work all the time, considering not all objects in the vector are `Plane`s. You can work it out with `dynamic_cast`, and check for a `NULL`, but that might be a little expensive. Like stated below, having `getRange` as a pure virtual method might work, but considering you might not want all `GeomObject` to implement it, `dynamic_cast` might be the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getRange` member function isn't part of the `GeomObject` definition, so you cannot call it through a pointer to `GeomObject`.

Try adding this in `GeomObject` :

```
virtual T getRange() = 0;
```

From further comments, it's made clear that `getRange` is specific to a `Plane`, so it cannot be added as a (pure) virtual member function in `GeomObject`.

In that case, you can still access `Plane::getRange`, but you'll have to downcast the pointer first. Eg. using [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) :

```
dynamic_cast<Plane<float>*>(g_objects[0])->getRange();
```

(omitting error checks for brevity).

Having to resort to this, is usually a code smell though. Ie. it's a sign that your design could be improved.

Comment: Okey, I agree. But in that vector I added an instance of Plane, which is still a GeomObject, but also a Plane. In Java, by casting, I would have been able to access the methods of Plane. I don't want to create a virtual getRange in my GeomObject class, because that's something specific of Plane.. is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: @Tarta You can cast like you do in Java.

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg suggested in his comment you need to read up on *downcasting*. Yes it can be done. No I don't recommend it, principally because it's brittle - you can use a literal downcast, but what happens if the actual object is not of the class to which you're downcasting? IMO you're better off using dynamic dispatching (`virtual` functions in C++). This also neatly handles whatever other shapes you have which derive from *GeomObject*.  Best of luck.

Comment: @Tarta : if `getRange` is specific to a `Plane`, then why are you trying to call it on a `GeomObject` ? As an aside, what you want to do is also not possible in Java (without casting).

Comment: @GioraGuttsait you are right, and you ALL are right! Understood the thing, thanks everyone :)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker because there is a specific part of my code where I know for sure that the first element of my vector will be a Plane, and therefore I am sure that I can access that method.. that's why I wanted to avoid to have a vector of only Planes.. because in my Project it can contains different type of objects

Comment: @SanderDeDycker so I would rather use casting instead of setting the contect of my vector specifically to only Planes

Comment: @Tarta : updated my answer to include the casting option.

Comment: I thought it was a common practice to do so, but many of you said that this is a bad design, so I am going to change it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Tarta : if you always have a `Plane` like you mentioned, then consider something like `struct Objects { Plane<float>* plane; vector<GeomObject<float>*> g_objects; };` instead.

Comment: @Sander yes it's more or less what I did indeed! I put out that single Plane from the vector! I thought it was a good design to put everything together but I was wrong ahah

Comment: The base class doesn't have to implement its derived class methods but it does have to be aware of them so it can direct the call to the right place.